# Is rsync completely read only?

Tags: rsync, readonly

If I use the following command:

```
rsync -r <source> <dest>
```

it only reads the files from source? Such that if all of the source directory were read-only, it should never have a problem, is that right?

Comment: @sudodus I think Kusalananda got the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time `rsync` deletes files from the source is when you use the option `--remove-source-files`.  See the `rsync` manual on your system for more info on this option (its semantics was changed in release 3.1.0).

Comment: Thanks, since I have control of which rsync commands get run, hopefully none of my end users' files get modified or deleted lulz

Comment: @AlexanderMills That could still happen if you use `--delete` (or `--delete-excluded` with some `--exclude` pattern) and you manage to confuse source and target (I've done that).  Always test run on throwaway data.